# Jagged edges before subsurf, or rounded corners after

Tags: faces

I am making a boat Hull. And problem is with edges. I am trying to do as much undestructive modeling as possible (less Edge loops as possible). For easier face export lates - lasercut and bend sheet. I use modifiers instead:
When i apply subsurf, sharp edges become rounded, i want them straight. I want smooth overal sides, but I get these jagged corners. Anyway to fix it?

[image: The sharp Edges should be sharp (blue). But when i apply subsurf modfier, the corners become round.]

[image: If I don't apply any subsurf, these edges are jagged. Is there some way to solve this?]

Comment: Model can be found here:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=q7sx3kdm" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/q7sx3kdm/)

Comment: if it is supposed to be used for future 3D print, why are you using creases, why not additional edge loops to sharp the edges? You will need them at the end

Comment: not it is not used for 3D print. I want to use UV unwrap for lasercutting.
Why not creases?

Comment: oh ok, but I'm not familiar enough with crease, you could easily get sharp edges with additional edge loops, but maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots file is shared (1st comment)

Comment: it looks like it's the EdgeSplit which messes up your mesh, I'm not familiar enough with this modifier, I hope someone will help^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your mirror modifier needs to be moved to the bottom of the modifier stack. If you subdivide it before mirroring, it will look like its separated, and it's very noticeable in the pictures you shared.

Making edges sharper is very easy. All you need to do is crease them. Just select any edges that need to be sharper/less smooth, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. You can then edit the crease value, a number between 0 and 1. It is 0 by default. 0 means that the subdivision surface will operate normally, and 1 means that it will not touch it at all and leave it completely sharp. The creased edges will also become purple, and this color will be lighter/darker depending on the crease value. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if your going to lasercut this, it's not a good idea to just cut out the UV map. The UV maps are flat, 2d representations of your model. Your model has a lot of curved surfaces, and that will all be lost inside the UV map.

Comment: thank you Eric for comment. Is there any other way to have a reliable flat then in blender?

Comment: P.S. That Crease did not work for me. It is much better result with the Bevel and weight. Anyway, I have got what I needed from this option.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was Bevel Modifier, with Weight Crease applied.
it worked perfectly. Model is easily controled.
Maybe this answer will help someone too.[image]

[image]
[image]